# Changing templates dynamically with xhtml2pdf and django

Tags: django, django-templates, xhtml2pdf

I want to switch between two named templates acording which kind of page the rendering is in (odd or even).

In another words, is it possible to loop through my context variable and change my template so I can print the paper and make a book out of it?.

Is there a way to detect a page break and change the template?

Here are my templates

```
  @page {
        size: a4 portrait;
        @frame header_frame { /* Static Frame */
        -pdf-frame-content: header_content;
        left: 80pt;
        width: 500pt;
        top: 20pt;
        height: 100pt;
    }
          @frame content_frame { /* Content Frame */
            left: 80pt;
            right: 20pt;
            width: 500pt;
            top: 110pt;
            height: 600pt; /*top: 90pt*/
        }

        @frame footer_frame {
            /* Another static Frame */
        -pdf-frame-content:footer_content;
        left: 80pt; width: 500pt; top: 720pt; height: 50pt;
        }

    }

    @page even{
        size: a4 portrait;
        @frame header_frame { /* Static Frame */
        -pdf-frame-content: header_content;
        right: 80pt;
        width: 500pt;
        top: 20pt;
        height: 100pt;
    }
          @frame content_frame { /* Content Frame */
            left: 20pt;
            right: 80pt;
            width: 500pt;
            top: 110pt;
            height: 600pt; /*top: 90pt*/
        }

        @frame footer_frame {
            /* Another static Frame */
        -pdf-frame-content:footer_content;
        right: 80pt; width: 500pt; top: 720pt; height: 50pt;
        }

    }
```

And my table

```
{% for item in data %}
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-row">
        {% if item.fracdspl|length == 7 %}

            <td style="padding-right:10px; font-weight: 500;">{{ item.fracdspl }}</td>
            <td style="width: 44%; padding: 0 10px; font-weight: 500;">{{ item.desc }}</td>
        {% else %}
            <td style="padding-right:10px ">{{ item.fracdspl }}</td>
            <td style="width: 44%; padding: 0 10px">{{ item.desc }}</td>
        {% endif %}


        <td>{{ item.unid_trf }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.adv }}.</td>
        <td style="width: 24%;padding-right:10px">{{ item.req }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.eua }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.can }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.ue }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.adv_exporta }}</td>
    </tr>


{% endfor %}
```